# Download song and store it in iPhone memory

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I need requirement for downloads songs and save them in iPhone memory using iphoneSDK, How can I implement to download the song and save to iPhone memory programmatically?

Comment: Mohan: From where u want 2 download songs??

Comment: @Amresh Kumar: I don't know yet, I need to finish fuctionality

Answer (score 1):

Quick one-liner:

```
NSData * theMusic = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/Music.mp3"]];
```

**EDIT**

In addition how to save the `NSData` object to the local storage.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
if ([theMusic writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"theMusic.mp3"] atomically:YES]) {
    // Success !
} else {
    // Error !  
}
```

Comment: Even though it's quite cool, you're missing two things here: error handling and saving the file to disk.

Comment: Error handing is indeed missing. I just answered how to _"store it in iphone memory"_ :)

Comment: I think the OP meant storage ;-)